# How to create a new pandas df with specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, address, like the one below:

```
    P_o_box    House_num
0        22        100
1        22        100
2        22        101
3        23        102
4        26        104
```

I'd like to create a new pd.dataframe, specific_address, that only returns specific values for 'P_o_Box' and 'House_num'. My code returns instead a data frame of boolean values. How can I only include the VALUES of the address dataframe to my new dataframe, specific_address?

```
specific_address = pd.DataFrame({'P_o_box': address['P_o_box'] == 22,
'House_num': address['House_num'] == 100})
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Also there isn’t really a need to create a new DataFrame with the constructor. You can slice and then copy to ensure it’s a new object

Answer (score 1):

Use the below:

```
specific_address=df[df.P_o_box.eq(22)&df.House_num.eq(100)]
print(specific_address)

   P_o_box  House_num
0       22        100
1       22        100
```

EDIT, for a new df:

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame({'P_o_box': df.loc[df['P_o_box'] == 22,'P_o_box'],
'House_num': df.loc[df['House_num'] == 100,'House_num']})
print(new_df)

   P_o_box  House_num
0       22      100.0
1       22      100.0
2       22        NaN
```

you can use: `new_df=new_df.dropna()` for dropping the `NaN` values

You can replace the `df` name as `address` if that is so.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this by creating a new dataframe? I'm trying to implement your code into the values part of my pandas dataframe but get an error.

Comment: @JohnLee what is the error? using pandas this should be the most convienient way

Comment: @JohnLee edited my answer for creating a new df. If that helps, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer, Thanks